# Send Data to another activity after the data gets updated in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

i have two activities activity 1 and activity 2 in android. From activity 1, I want to send data to activity 2. My activity 1 gets updated anytime when activity is minimized then also. I want to send the updated data to another activity 2 anytime time when data in activity 1 gets updated....

Comment: save that data in sharedprefrence..you can access it from any activity..if you can save it..

Comment: But without updating my activity 2. I want the data. My activity won't be refreshed so shared preference is not an option.

Comment: then use something to update it in background..

Comment: When the activity is minimized, how does it know the data was updated?

Comment: I have inserted a log in it....

Comment: @MeenalSharma : by the way, there is a way to get notified upon change in `SharedPreference` using [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html)

Comment: the best way to handle this is to do that background work in an Service, and from MyActivity2 bind to it and listen for updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send data using handler to another activity.
Step 1:

```
//-- Create Handler in destination activity.

public static Handler handler;

handler=new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //-- retreiving data
        String data=msg.obj.toString();
        int i=msg.arg1;

        return false;
    }
});
```

Step 2:

```
//-- Passing data from source activity.

Message msg=new Message();
msg.arg1=10;//Pass int value
msg.obj="Test Message";//Pass any type of value
DestinationActivity.handler.sendMessage(msg);// DestinationActivity is your activity from u want to pass data.
```

Comment: I doubt if it leaks memory due to static handler.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a CallBack and a Singleton, the idea is this:

```
public class Mediator{

    static MyCallBack mCallBack;

    public static void setCallback(MyCallBack cb){
        mCallBack = cb;
    }

    public static void callCallBack(Object data){
        if(mCallBack != null){
            mCallBack.onUpdate(data);
        }
    }

    public static interface MyCallBack{
        public void onUpdate(Object data);
    }
}

first extends Activity{
    //methods and fields
    //...
    private void update(){
        //some logic...
        String someData = "The data";
        Mediator.callCallBack(someData);
    }
}

second extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(){
        //...
        Mediator.setCallback(new Mediator.MyCallBack(){
            public void onUpdate(Object data){
                //LOGIC WITH DATA HERE
            }
        });
    }
    //methods and fields
    //...
}
```